# Float Right fica sobrepondo div e invadindo div de baixo

Tags: css, floating

Eaí pessoal, eu to aqui mais uma vez pedindo ajuda, eu tentei de tudo, até usei `overflow:hidden`, mas ficou muito pior, então eu preciso de ajuda, eu tenho

O código da div:

```
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 2em 3em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 11pt;
    color: #656565;
    line-height: 130%;
```

O código do float right:

```
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    max-width: 96%;
    padding: 5px 3px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 0 20px 20px;
```

Foto de Como fica:
[image: Como está] 
JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqc6m1h6/1/

Comment: Coloque o html/css corrspondente/relevante para facilitar facilitar a resolução do problema sff

Comment: @Miguel O Css está colocado, o da div com `float:right` e da div parent.

Comment: Facilitava ver o html também, o relevante, só com isso não consigo ser objetivo e estaria a adivinhar. Porque não faz um jsfiddle? sff

Comment: @Miguel JsFiddle adicionado, fica dificil ver esse problema lá, mas coloquei do mesmo jeito.

Comment: O que pretente? QUando diz que "ficou muito pior" o que fica?

Comment: Ele corta a imagem em alguns tamanhos de tela, eu tentei usar ao invés de float um `text-align:right`, mas sem sucesso, e o float fica fazendo a div ir para direita que é o necessário, mas também faz ela sobrepor a div, e isso é ruim por que ela vai para a div de baixo, algumas vezes forçando o `<h2>` se adaptar indo para a esquerda.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43143/discussion-between-miguel-and-raphael-caldas).

Comment: Se utiliza o bootstrap, já tentou após o fim da div criar uma div <div class="clearfix"></div>?

Comment: @GustavoTinoco Faz uma resposta aí, pegou bem, valeu, eu tinha esquecido desse codigo, eu nem uso bootstrap mas me lembrei o codigo que tem dentro dele, muito obrigado! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É simples, segue o exemplo....

Exemplo:

```css
  .clearfix {
    overflow: auto;
  }

.elem {
    border: solid #6AC5AC 3px;
    position: relative;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
     
       <div class="elem">
         
        <img style="float:right" src="http://pt-br.learnlayout.com/images/ilta.png" alt="An Image">
        <p>
<span>Pareçe que ficou estranho a imagem do lado com este conteúdo digitado não é mesmo??</span>
        </p>

    
   </div>
<div class="clear">Adicione a clearfix agora..</div>
<br><br>
      <div class="elem clearfix">
         
        <img style="float:right" src="http://pt-br.learnlayout.com/images/ilta.png" alt="An Image">
        <p>

<span>Normalizou agora? Parece que ficou normal....</span>
        </p>

    
   </div>
```